# Finding a length of a diagonal of a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider the following construction:

[image]

What we do know are the length $L = |AB|$ and the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I want the length $|AD|$ of the diagonal AD.

The only thing I managed to do so far is to get the angle $\hat{AEB} = \pi - \alpha - \beta$ and $\hat{AEC} = \alpha + \beta$. Of course, $|CD| = |AB| = L$ and $|AC| = |DB|$ is still missing.

How to find the length of the diagonal AD?

Comment: Do you know what the Cosine Rule is?

Comment: @CalvinLin: surely you mean the Sine Rule?

Comment: Hint: Forget about the quadrilateral. Just focus on the triangle $ABE$.

Comment: @TonyK Both / Either / Or. Trying to get a sense of what / how much OP knows.

Comment: I didn't know it, but I can understand it pretty well. So yeah, with the Sine Rule and the Hint from @TonyK I guess I managed to find AE, which is AD/2 with $|AE| = L\sin(\alpha)/\sin(\alpha+\beta)$ if I'm right?

Comment: Yes, well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, $|AD|=2|AE|$

Using the sine law on triangle $ABE$ ...
$$ \frac {|AE|}{\sin(\alpha) }=\frac L{sin(\pi-(\alpha+\beta))}$$
So
$$|AD|=\frac{2L\sin(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}$$